# How can I have multiple forms share a common menu in a Winforms app?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, menu

I have an **existing** .NET Winforms app made with a few complex forms, and

1) the forms all live for the life of the app, and

2) only one form is displayed at a time (the user switches between the forms)

I need for these forms to share a common menu that will be processed by a single business-logic controller.  (The visible form is also continuously updated by the controller)

Is there a way to the same menu appear at the top of each form and have the menu processed by their common controller without having to make it an MDI application?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Create a base form with the menu.  Then the individual forms can inherit this base form, automatically getting the same menu.  To refactor the existing forms, edit the form.cs and change

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
```

to

```
 public partial class Form1 : MyBaseForm
```

Comment: I would also add your menu commands as private methods that call a virtual or abstract On<MenuItemName> function so you can handle the actions differently on each form.  For common actions you should be able to code them into your base form directly.

Answer (score 1):

Build the menu in a custom control (user control), and then add that control to each of your forms.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, but my answer might still help people.

This class would be a good start to manage this:

Disclaimer: Not tested, but the idea should work.

```
static class FormService{
    /*
     * Members
     */
    private static Dictionary<string, Form> _forms = new Dictionary<string, Form>();
    private static Dictionary<string, Type> _types = new Dictionary<string, Type>();       
    private static Form opened_ = null;

    /*
     * Properties
     */

    public static Form Opened

    /*
     * Methods
     */
    public static void register(string className, Type type){
        if (_types.ContainsKey(className))throw new Exception("Form already registered");
        _forms.Add(className, Activator.CreateInstance(type));
        _types.Add(className, type);

    }

    // use with Convert.ChangeType
    public static Type getFormType(string className){
        return _types[className];
    }

    public static void open(string className){
        if (opened_ != null){
            opened_.Hide();
        }
        opened_ = _forms[className];
        opened_.ShowDialog(); // show dialog will block main menu actions
    }

}
```